# Is there a way to disable a group of radiobuttons associated to the same Tkinter variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have used a for loop to create a group of radiobuttons that would select an item like so:

```
modes = [('Item A',20),('Item B',100),('Item C',180),('Item D',280)]
for item in modes:
        button = Radiobutton(picker, text=item[0], variable=item_choice, value=item[0], command=select_item)
        button.place(x = item[1], y = 180)
```

is there a way to disable these radiobutton via the variable `item_choice` which they are all associated to? Since I do not have variable names associated to each button. I tried `button.config(state=DISABLED)` but it does not seem to work. Is there a way to disable all the buttons associated to the variable `item_choice` ? For further context - I used a loop to create the radiobuttons because in my actual code there is around 10 radiobuttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append them to a list, and later on iterate over the list of buttons, and disable them.

```
btnlist = []
for item in modes:
    button = ....
    button.place()
    btnlist.append(button)
```

And then later...

```
for button in btnlist:
   button.config(...)
```

If they are containerized, you could address all child widgets of the container.
If they are in a frame for example:

```
widgets = frame.winfo_children()
for widget in widgets:
    widget.config(...)
```

##### Note: I use widgets in the for loop, you should type check it against buttons if you want to address all buttons. This takes every widget into context.

If you need entry boxes for example, you would check it like so:

```
if widget.winfo_class() == 'Entry':
```

Comment: You can also use `if isinstance(widget, Entry):` instead of `if widget.winfo_class() == 'Entry':`